# Issue with doxygen .dox files

Tags: doxygen

I am trying to run doxygen on some source files for a project that I downloaded source files for. The files are located in the following directories:

- doc/ - Documentation files, such as .dox files.
- src/ - Source files

My settings in my doxygen.config file are:

```
INPUT                  = ../ .

FILE_PATTERNS          = *.h *.dox *.dxx
```

When I run doxygen (`doxygen doxygen.config`), it generates all of the documentation from the .h files correctly, but it does not generate the mainpage correctly. I have a file titled `intro.dox` in the `doc` folder, with a command `\mainpage Documentation Index`, and a bunch of text, but doxygen is not using this to generate the main page.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are (at least) two possible reasons for this:

1. You are not including the `/doc` directory in you `INPUT` list. Try modifying this to

   ```
   INPUT = ../ . ../doc
   ```

   Did you mean to write `../doc` instead of `../`? I am guessing that your `doxygen.config` file is in your `src` directory. If this is not the case can you make this clear in the question.
2. Doxygen requires that your documentation files (your `.dox` files) are plain text with your text wrapped with Doxygen C++ comments (i.e. `/** ... */`).

Comment: I figured out the problem. The c++ comment was not closed by a */. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing where `doxygen.config` is located, and since you are using relative paths in `INPUT`, it is difficult to determine what might cause this, however since the files you are looking for are in parallel directories, it is possible that doxygen is not search recursively for your files. You may want to confirm that `RECURSIVE` is set to `YES` in `doxygen.config`.

Comment: RECURSIVE is set to YES, and doxygen.config is in the doc folder, which is the folder I am running doxygen from.