# How to generate .dox files?

Tags: javadoc, doxygen, doxygen-wizard

I would like to generate a documentation for my source code using Doxygen. I have a readymade script for that that use Doxygen. The command to generate that is :

```
call "%doxygen%" %%f.dox > %%f.log 2> %%f.err
```

I was wondering How to generate `.dox` files ? using *DoxyWizard* for instance is it possible ? is there another way ?

As starting stage, I can use the command 
`doxygen -g configFile` 
to generate a template configuration file to be edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension .dox is normally used for special pages in doxygen.

You can use the regular doxygen commands found here:

http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html

Normally, you start a special page via @page or @mainpage.

The template you generated is the configuration for doxygen, there you define how/which output is generated, which files to include and more.

The documentation for the configuration is here:

http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html

So the first is content (pages, like commenting code), the second is toolchain configuration.

You can explicitly configure doxygen to include your .dox file via

`INCLUDE += myfile.dox`

in your .doxycfg.

Also see these questions on SO:

- [How to include custom files in Doxygen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052036/how-to-include-custom-files-in-doxygen)
- [Can Doxygen process pages other than MainPage.dox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151360/can-doxygen-process-pages-other-than-mainpage-dox)
- [Issue with doxygen .dox files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12207872/issue-with-doxygen-dox-files)
- [How to make an introduction page with Doxygen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502426/how-to-make-an-introduction-page-with-doxygen)